# magento 1.9 login page not showing any messages

Tags: magento-1.9, login, messages

My website - http://www.qnhealth.com/customer/account/login/ login works ok.  But if there is any invalid login like:  email: abc@abc.com password: 123456
there the invalid message not showing i checked the login.phtml there message block is called properly(`<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>`) and all other page showing the all messages properly can anyone help me

Login form

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Customer login form template
 *
 * @see app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
 */
/** @var $this Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login */
?>
<style type="text/css">
<?php 

$str=file_get_contents('/home/qnhealth/public_html/css/login.css', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$str = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $str);
$str = str_replace(': ', ':', $str);
$str = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $str);
echo $str;

 ?>
</style>
<div class="Page_Container">
<div class="account-login<?php if (!$this->helper('customer')->isRegistrationAllowed()) echo ' login-only' ?>">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php if ($this->helper('customer')->isRegistrationAllowed()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->__('Login or Create an Account') ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->__('Login'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php /*$message1=Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()
        ->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') 
        ->getMessages(true))->getGroupedHtml() ; ?>
        <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml()*/ ?>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form" class="scaffold-form">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <div class="col2-set">
            <?php if ($this->helper('customer')->isRegistrationAllowed()): ?>
            <div class="col-1 new-users">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Here?') ?></h2>
                    <p class="form-instructions"><?php echo $this->__('Registration is free and easy!') ?></p>
                    <ul class="benefits">
                        <li><?php echo $this->__('Faster checkout') ?></li>
                        <li><?php echo $this->__('Save multiple shipping addresses') ?></li>
                        <li><?php echo $this->__('View and track orders and more') ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Create an Account')) ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('persistent')->getCreateAccountUrl($this->getCreateAccountUrl()) ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></span></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php // This column should be col-1 if the registration column is not displayed ?>
            <div class="<?php if ($this->helper('customer')->isRegistrationAllowed()): ?>col-2<?php else: ?>col-1<?php endif; ?> registered-users">
                <div class="content fieldset">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Already registered?') ?></h2>
                    <p class="form-instructions"><?php echo $this->__('If you have an account with us, please log in.') ?></p>
                    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li>
                            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Email Address')) ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="pass" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Password')) ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a>
                        </li>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Login')) ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('checkout')->isContextCheckout()): ?>
            <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below to your phtml file.

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

Comment: i have already tried with these cods but no change nothing display   <?php $message1=Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()
        ->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') 
        ->getMessages(true))->getGroupedHtml() ; ?>
  <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>